# UnicodeEncodeError: crawel web using Python3 and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
html = urlopen("http://www.xyafc.edu.cn/xyacnews/cnews/")
news = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(news.title.encode('utf8'))
```

the result:

```
b'<title>\xe6\xa0\xa1\xe5\x9b\xad\xe6\x96\xb0\xe9\x97\xbb</title>'
```

### The website

http://www.xyafc.edu.cn/xyacnews/cnews/  The page's charset is gb2312. I google the Internet to find answers, but these are not work. How can I get the right `news.title`?

Comment: if page use `gb2312` so why do you use ` utf-8` ? why don't you print without encoding ?

Comment: I use `print(news.title)` and get `<title>校园新闻</title>` (Linux Mint, Bash console with `utf-8`)

Comment: BTW: what do you get when you print without `.encode('utf8')` ? If incorrect string then maybe problem is not string but console which use different encoding. Windows mostly use `cp125x` (CodePage) also known as `win-125x` http://imgur.com/aWIDjwT

Comment: Thank you! You are right! I got `<title>校园新闻</title>` in my bash.(Mac 10.12). The wrong answer is run on the atom-runner!

Comment: some console doesn't inform Python what encoding is used by console and then `print()` has problem to encode it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first when you want to change the encode of html, do it in urlopen
than `encode` means str >> byte, that's way you print out a `b'....'`.

just get rid of the encode.